# Ionic scrollbar color white

Tags: ionic-framework, colors, scrollbar

I want my ionic app to have a white vertical scrollbar.

I've tried a lot within css but could not cope with the problem. Also web search does not give a hint.

Can somebody help?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Might be you have to look http://ionicframework.com/docs/theming/overriding-ionic-variables/

Comment: And which one of them? There are so many and scrollbar isnot one of them

Comment: did you find any answers? I think I have the same problem with you.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you use dark theme.
If don't need, delete dark theme.

In `index.html`

change from

```
<meta name="color-scheme" content="light dark" />
```

to

```
<meta name="color-scheme" content="light" />
```

https://ionicframework.com/docs/theming/dark-mode#adjusting-system-ui-components